# Different output when parsing website

Tags: php, asp.net, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape the table containing "Institution Name:, Institution Type: etc" from the following website
http://cricos.deewr.gov.au/Institution/InstitutionDetails.aspx?ProviderID=00001
Using PHP and simple_html_dom i've generated the following code:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://cricos.deewr.gov.au/Institution/InstitutionDetails.aspx?ProviderID=00001');
$element = $html->find("table");
echo $element[1];
?>
```

I've iterated through tables (e.g $element[0], $element[1], $element[2] etc)
But do not find the correct table.

I then tried the same code on a local copy of the website:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('Institution Details.htm');
$element = $html->find("table");
echo $element[1];
?>
```

And it works I can see the table I am looking for under $element[1].
Why does it work on a local copy but no when using the url? How do I make the first set of code work?
Thankyou

Comment: you'll in both cases get the table with id = `ctl00_cphDefaultPage_tabContainer_sheetCourseList_courseList_gridSearchResults` . whats wrong with that?

Comment: In the first case I get that. The second one I get the table with style="vertical-align:top;" Which is what I want. Did you save the webpage and run the script on it? I used google chrome and saved as "webpage html only"

Comment: Yes I've done so. Which version of simple_html_dom you are using?

Comment: I just tried with 1.5 ($Rev: 196 $) aswell. I get this table:
http://i.imgur.com/kEcDN.png

Comment: It does not work with either of those versions of simple_html_dom the table I want to extract is this one http://i.imgur.com/e5Hc5.png